# How to truly remove Firebase from a Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I've installed flutterfire (Messaging) in my project, but then changed my mind and took a different path.
So how I can get rid of anything firebase related in my app?

I'm on Windows 11 using VSCode as an editor.

The problem is that now whenever I run my app, after a while I receive the following debug message:

```
Making request to: https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3
```

The request gives a 200 results, so it looks like it works.
I do not have any flutterfire reference in my project, already took the following steps:

- npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
- dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli
- removed all projects from firebase console
- found no references to firebase in project folder
- removed the android folder and rebuilt it
- removed the root build folder and rebuilt it

Looks like nothing worked, that http call is still there and I can't figure out where it comes from. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Edit: after digging deeper I noticed the source for that call isn't Firebase itself but mobile_scanner package. Started doing so only after the firebase installation and removal. Filed a bug report to the package owner.

Comment: No other dependances using firebase? No firebase entry on the android project?

Comment: I looked for occourrences of "fire" in any file and folder of the project and found none. Is there a public folder outside of the project maybe?

Comment: Might be something in the Flutter engine? I _never ever_ used Firebase for anything and I can still see this in the log, too. And not any of the dependent packages, either, because `flutter pub deps` should show that.

Answer (score -1):

remove libraries manually from pubspec.yaml and remove firebase json file from your project then go to firebase console and remove project that should do it .

Comment: Already done as said in the question.

Comment: There isn't any firebase json anywhere and anyhting firebase related doesn't appear in the yaml. (already updated pub packages)